# SQL Server XML Parsing with concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a set of XML as follows in a column "test" of type xml. The table is "cow".

```
<p>
  <k>query</k>
  <v>
    <w id="a" name="b">
      <p>
        <op>IN</op>
        <v name="apple">1</v>
        <v name="pear">2</v>
        <v name="kiwi">3</v>
        <v name="carrot">4</v>
      </p>
    </w>
  </v>
</p>
```

I want to write  a select statement that returns 1 row and 1 column with a value of "apple, pear, kiwi, carrot". Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using XQuery's [data()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187038.aspx) function which takes a sequence of items and atomizes them:

```
CREATE TABLE #cow(cow XML);

INSERT INTO #cow
SELECT (N'<p>
            <k>query</k>
            <v>
            <w id="a" name="b">
                <p>
                <op>IN</op>
                <v name="apple">1</v>
                <v name="pear">2</v>
                <v name="kiwi">3</v>
                <v name="carrot">4</v>
                </p>
            </w>
            </v>
        </p>');      

select cow.query('data(/p/v/w/p/v/@name)') as example from #cow

#   example
#1  apple pear kiwi carrot
```

For comma-separated values:

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(255), cow.query('data(/p/v/w/p/v/@name)')),
               ' ', ', ') as example from #cow

#   example
#1  apple, pear, kiwi, carrot
```

Comment: I like this, +1 from my side, but be aware, that the comma replacement won't work, if the concatenated string contain spaces...

Answer (score 2):

If there's no other criteria and all you need to do is retrieve those values as a single thing, you can do it something like this:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + A.B.value('@name', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
FROM cow
CROSS APPLY test.nodes('p/v/w/p/v') A(B)
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
```

Ironically, the `FOR XML PATH` has no bearing on the fact that it's an XML column to begin with.